# How to manage and version Keycloak config evolutions?

Tags: configuration, migration, keycloak

I have the following use case that has been bugging me for... well years now.

I'm using Keycloak as a SSO for multiple applications. Each time I create a new application it is registered as a new client and i may or may not add a specific user, or a specific role, or a scope, or even fine grained permissions. In short: whatever is doable in Keycloak.

The thing is all my applications have their own git and i'd like to centralize the Keycloak evolutions without needing manual intervention (currently everything related to Keycloak is manual). I would like to be able to create / configure / remove elements from Keycloak programmaticaly.

As a note, Keycloak is being deployed through Kubernetes.
My applications are generally JVM oriented but that's not always the case (I also have some ruby and python).

I imagined having a specific project to do this but I feel like i'd be reinventing the wheel considering there are existing tools to migrate basically anything. Plus it would mean that project should evolve each time I create a new application thus requiring some kind of ordering or synchronisation in the migration process. I'm just not sure how I should approach a specific case like this one that will probably require some custom scripts.

Are there any existing tools, techniques or patterns that would help me solve this ?

Thanks